# C++ - Compiling for windows XP SP1 using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-xp

I have a project written in Visual Studio 2013.
We need to compile it somehow to work in Windows XP SP1

What do you suggest?
It's possible (but not preferable) to migrate it to VS2012.
The project works with statically linking with the CRT. We prefer to leave it that way.